# how to get image size in bytes from imageview (android)

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-size

i am working on an wallpaper app in which i am receiving images from **Picasa Web Album** in `GridView` and `Full Screen ImageView`.

i want to save `ImageView` loaded image using `image bytes size, to prevent duplicate save, but i don't know`how to get image bytes size from ImageView.`

this is my code:

```
int intHeight = fullImageView.getHeight();
            int intWidth = fullImageView.getWidth();                    

            String dirname2 = "/Amazing Wallpapers HD/";

            File myDir2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath() + dirname2);

            myDir2.mkdirs();

            String fname2 = "image" + intHeight+ intWidth +".jpeg";
            File file2 = new File(myDir2, fname2);

            if (file2.exists())
                file2.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(_context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**Note:** i am asking about size of image in bytes or kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with **Picasa** you can simply get photo description which will gives you a lot of unique features in order to use it in your work:

```
photo.getDescription().getPlainText()
```

you will find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#PhotosInfo).

Answer (score -1):

You can use BitmapFactory.Options for that. It'll only extract the meta data of the image not the image as a whole.You should be able to get enough data from there to ensure you wont have a duplicate.
For further reading: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)